# Stream Vs Handle, respondHTTP throws error

Tags: sockets, haskell, stream

`Network.accept` returns me a Handle on accepting a connection, which i am passing as an argument to `respondHTTP` (from Network.HTTP.Base)
Their types are,

```
accept :: Socket -> IO (Handle, HostName, PortNumber)
respondHTTP :: HStream ty => HandleStream ty -> Response ty -> IO ()
```

This line -- [git-code](https://github.com/madhavan020985/haskell-examples/blob/master/simpleserver.hs#L43)

```
handleResponse = Kleisli (print ||| respondHTTP c)
```

, throws error as,

```
simpleserver.hs:43:53:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Network.TCP.HandleStream ty’
                with actual type ‘Handle’
    Relevant bindings include
      handleResponse :: Kleisli IO (Either b (Response ty)) ()
        (bound at simpleserver.hs:43:5)
    In the first argument of ‘respondHTTP’, namely ‘c’
    In the second argument of ‘(|||)’, namely ‘respondHTTP c’
```

How can i convert the `Handle` (returned from `Network.accept)` into a `Stream` before passing it to `respondHTTP`?

Answer (score 1):

A `HandleStream` from `Network.TCP` and a `Handle` from `System.IO` are two different things; there is no superclass-subclass relationship.  They are not interchangeable.

Create your `Socket`, then pass it to [`socketConnection`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.20/docs/Network-TCP.html#v:socketConnection), not `accept`.  That will return a `HandleStream` like you need.